# Почему на практике семантика перемещения медленней семантики копирования?

Tags: c++, перемещение

Вечер в хату, многоуважаемые кодеры.

Прочитал статью про семантику перемещения, ссылки на r-value и std::move(), после чего пошел радостный проверять, сколько времени можно выиграть, быстренько и лениво написав две реализации бабблсорта:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

template <typename T>
bool check(T* arr, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) return 0;
    };
    return 1;
}

template <typename T>
void bubblesortcopy(T* arr, int n)
{
    while (true)
    {
        bool op = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j + 1] < arr[j])
            {
                T h = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = h;
                op = true;
            };
        };
        if (!op) return;
        n--;
    };
};

template <typename T>
void bubblesortmove(T* arr, int n)
{
    while (true)
    {
        bool op = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j + 1] < arr[j])
            {
                T h { std::move(arr[j + 1]) };
                arr[j + 1] = std::move(arr[j]);
                arr[j] = std::move(h);
                op = true;
            };
        };
        if (!op) return;
        n--;
    };
};

int main()
{
    int n;
    clock_t start;
    clock_t end;
    std::cin >> n;
    int* arr1 = new int[n];
    int* arr2 = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr1[i] = rand();
        arr2[i] = arr1[i];
    };
    start = clock();
    bubblesortcopy(arr1, n);
    end = clock();
    if(check(arr1, n)) std::cout << difftime(end, start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
    start = clock();
    bubblesortmove(arr2, n);
    end = clock();
    if(check(arr2, n)) std::cout << difftime(end, start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
    delete[] arr1;
    delete[] arr2;
};
```

В итоге ожидания и реальность сильно отличаются:

[image: ...]

Объясните нубику, в чем заключается ошибка? Или это фича, а не баг?

Comment: Перемещение инта не должно отличаться по скорости от копирования, как минимум в релизном билде...

Comment: 1. https://ideone.com/Mi6x9w & https://ideone.com/RLwIqr 2. Не надо под дебагом производительность измерять. Может его угораздило функцию вызывать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так вы же "перемещаете" обычные `int`-ы! У типа `int` семантика перемещения - это и есть семантика копирования. Неудивительно, что ничего не меняется. (Подозреваю, что вы мерили время в отладочной версии кода, из-за чего получилось якобы даже замедление. Мерить время в отладочной версии кода бессмысленно.)

Какая-то "ускоряющая" семантика перемещения возможна только на уровне пользовательского кода (внутри конструкторов перемещения и перемещающих операторов присваивания), написанного в первую очередь для объектов, которые занимаются менеджментом внутренних ресурсов. В подавляющем большинстве случаев "ускорение" на основе семантики перемещения основывается на том, что для типов с многоуровневой внутренней структурой *неглубокое копирование* (shallow copying) быстрее *глубокого копирования* (deep copying).

Например, тип `std::vector` - тип с "глубокой" внутренней структурой (он обычно хранит внутри себя указатель на массив элементов) и имеет нетривиальную семантику перемещения, реализованную авторами библиотеки. Попробуйте еще раз ваш же эксперимент с `T == std::vector` вместо `T == int`. И посмотрите, что получится. Возьмите массивы подлиннее. (Вариант с `T == std::string` может подойти для этой цели, а может и не подойти, ибо в некоторых реализациях копирование `std::string` реализуется через reference counting.)

К типу `int` все это не имеет никакого отношения, разумеется. Для типа `int` перемещение - это копирование. Для всех фундаментальных типов перемещение - это обычное копирование. Для всех "плоских" типов перемещение - это обычное копирование. Т.е. например, для типа

```
struct S
{
  int x; double y; char z[20];
};
```

вы тоже не получите никакого ускорения от семантики перемещения.

Еще раз: нетривиальная (т.е. не совпадающая с копированием) семантика перемещения - это всегда функциональность пользовательского/библиотечного уровня. Т.е. семантика перемещения всегда пишется *руками*, в виде перемещающих конструкторов и перемещающих операторов присваивания. Все это пишется либо вашими руками, либо руками автора библиотеки. Если вы ничего такого не писали, значит в вашем коде нет никакой нетривиальной семантики перемещения. От того, что вы применили `std::move` она ниоткуда не появится. `std::move` - это просто каст, он "ничего не делает".

Comment: Искренне благодарю за доступное и исчерпывающее объяснение!

Answer (score 5):

На моей машине, VC++2017 с включенными оптимизациями для `n == 20000` по 50 экспериментам

```
copy   0.454 ± 0.010
move   0.465 ± 0.010
```

Т.е. в пределах погрешности - совпадает...

**QED**, ибо для `int` семантика move == семантике copy...

А теперь меняем `int` на `string`, и генерируем случайные строки по 100 символов

```
string s;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) s += 'a'+rand()%26;
```

Дальше - все то же самое, только массивы по 10000, чтоб не так долго ждать :)
По результатам 14 экспериментов (все равно терпения не хватило):

```
copy   3.656 ± 0.039
move   0.459 ± 0.006
```

Результат говорит сам за себя :)

Comment: В пределах погрешности - да, но почему-то на ideone с move int получается медленнее всегда. Какая-то странная погрешность. https://ideone.com/Mi6x9w & https://ideone.com/RLwIqr

Comment: @Qwertiy Забавно, но определенное расхождение в ассемблере есть. Причем никак не в части `move()`...

Comment: @Qwertiy А вот при компиляции x86 - все один в один...

Comment: А можно эту разницу увидеть?

Comment: Код в студию пожалуйста, или ссылку на гит

Comment: @Andrey https://drive.google.com/open?id=1f57V36qH320rq0NEAork0fpqKPPW_jr0 и https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LqoHEAUVIz1XdT2tE6f_yBuhvQEtoERg

Comment: @Qwertiy "Кстати, это ответ и на ваш вопрос..." (с) Анекдот Компилировано VC++ 2017 x64 строкой `cl /std:c++latest /O2 /Ot /Oi /Ox /Oy /Ob2 /EHsc /FC /W4 /nologo /MT /FAs qest.cpp`

Comment: Ой..Длинный... Я diff хотел в 2 колонки, а тут даже не найду, что с чем сравнивать :(

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну вот в две колонки: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TTq25TJzf18vja8aV4r50Xaujtsh4obj Почему и что так - не ко мне, что вижу, то и пою...

Comment: Попробуйте на godbolt и посмотрите что за код получился, если интересно. Там вообще можно много интересного узнать о том как компилятор копирование или инициализацию  реализует на разных архитектурах